# Can I delete the .iso file after installing ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10

I've been using Ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 8 and I installed it a long time back using a .iso file which is roughly 800mb in size. Can I delete it now ? Will it affect my PC?
Can I do the same for 13.10?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, the ISO file is just a disc image used for creating Live CD's or bootable ~USB's for installation purposes, there is no need for it to sit on your desktop/usb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can delete the `.iso` files. That will not affect the existing system anyway. But you may need it any later time for re-installation or repair.

Unless there is acute crisis of disk space it is recommended to preserve the `.iso` file of the existing distro you are using.